# Search a string with spaces similar to full string in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, postgresql

I have an issue which I am facing I would really appreciate your help.

I am using java and connecting it to postgres DB. I tried writing a query with `LIKE` and it works, but what I am looking is `regex` that works similar to `LIKE` where white spaces are also counted.

For example lets say we have the following entries in our array from the results of the DB as

> "ca ts", "cats", "ca ts"

etc. When I type

> "c a ts"

in the search filter I should retrieve all the above from that array which has all the results from the database.

Comment: So you want to do a text pattern match that ignores spaces?

Comment: yes, exactly that is what I want

Comment: Then why do your comments on other answers mention arrays? Where do arrays come into this?

Comment: @CraigRinger I have mentioned arrays because I need a text pattern match for contents of an array. The contents of the array are the one's I have mentioned above along with some other values, now I want a pattern match to retrieve all the results basing on the pattern

Comment: But that's not a array, it's just a string.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with replacing spaces from input and search pattern:

```
    String input = "a b c";
    String searchPattern = "ab  c";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(searchPattern.replace(" ", ""));
    System.out.println(pat.matcher(input.replace(" ", "")).matches());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `regex` for it. EG here `'c a ts'` is "like" `'ca ts'`:

```
b=# select replace('c a ts',' ','') like replace('ca ts',' ','') as example;
 example
---------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: yes, I have already used LIKE and I could get it from the DB. but my issue is I have all the those results in an array and the search is to be done in that array to get all such items from that array. As whenever we are using we are hitting the DB and we want to reduce the dependancy on DB

Comment: You keep changing what the stated problem is. Define the *actual* problem you are trying to solve, in detail. If there are arrays involved, show how. etc.